# Installation of DBD::Oracle failing on spaces in path on Windows

Tags: oracle, perl, windows-server-2012, cpan, strawberry-perl

Attempting to install DBD::Oracle in my Strawberry Perl (v5.16.3) on my Windows 2012 server.  I'm using the command:

```
cpanm DBD::Oracle
```

Unfortunately, I believe it is failing because there is a space in the ORACLE_HOME path.  Looking in the logs I see the following:

```
gcc -c  -IC:/Program Files/Oracle/ora92/oci/include -IC:/Program Files/Oracle/ora92/rdbms/demo -IT:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\auto\DBI     -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2     -DVERSION=\"1.74\"    -DXS_VERSION=\"1.74\"  "-IT:\strawberry\perl\lib\CORE"  -Wall -Wno-comment -DUTF8_SUPPORT -DORA_OCI_VERSION=\"9.2.0.1\" Oracle.c
gcc: error: Files/Oracle/ora92/oci/include: No such file or directory
gcc: error: Files/Oracle/ora92/rdbms/demo: No such file or directory
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'Oracle.o'
-> FAIL Installing DBD::Oracle failed. See T:\strawberry\data\.cpanm\work\1485813890.9528\build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

So, is there any way to get dmake (or whatever program is doing this) to put double quotes around the include paths?

Or, am I barking up the wrong tree here?   Is there something else I should consider?

Unfortunately, for various reason, re-installing the Oracle client somewhere else is not an option.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Can you `set ORA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Oracle\ora92\...`?

Comment: It looks like a bug [here](https://metacpan.org/source/PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.74/Makefile.PL#L377) in Makefile.PL. You should [submit a bug report](https://github.com/pythian/DBD-Oracle/issues).

Comment: @mob Thanks mob - that got me through to the next error `In file included from Oracle.xs:1:0:Oracle.h:37:17: fatal error: oci.h: No such file or directory`  For some reason, oci.h has not been included in the client install.   I can't find it anywhere on the drive.   I'll talk to the administrator about installing it.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  Yes, I will.  I haven't dealt with Makefiles in over 2 decades, so I wasn't sure where the problem was.  Thanks!

Comment: @FrankRalphBob Makefile.PL is actually just a Perl script. It generates the actual Makefile.